# How to always refresh file loaded by ajax, avoiding cached file

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, caching

First I load external JavaScript file with following code (it appends `ext_chat.js` script source to current DOM):

```
var protocol = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://');
(function(d, t, p) {
   var g = d.createElement(t),
      s = d.getElementById('Chat_Script');
   g.src = p + 'mydomain.lc/js/ext_chat.js';
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s.nextSibling);
}(document, 'script', protocol));
```

Inside the `ext_chat.js`. Here I'm including the CSS file:

```
function r(f) { 
/in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('r(' + f + ')', 9) : f()
}

r(function () {
    includeCSSfile(getBaseUrl() + '/css/ext_chat.css')); // getBaseUrl() gives correct url
});

function includeCSSfile(href) {
    var head_node = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link_tag = document.createElement('link');
    link_tag.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link_tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    link_tag.setAttribute('href', href);
    link_tag.setAttribute('media', 'screen');
    head_node.appendChild(link_tag);
}
```

On first load, the CSS file is included fine. After the first time, when the page is loaded all changes to the `ext_chat.css` file are not reflected, and cached file is being used instead.
How can I force the CSS file to reload every time the page loads, instead of referring to the cached one?

Comment: It's impossible without reloading page. Instead of including external file you can do it by using javascript

Comment: maybe you can do it if you add a timestamp to the href, so it's unique: `link_tag.setAttribute('href', href + '?timestamp=' + Date.now());`
If you set ?timestamp=1234 or just ?1234 shouldn't make a diffrence, it just have to be unique

Comment: `link_tag.setAttribute('href', href+"?ts="+new Date().getTime());` could work - note `Date.now()` is IE9+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, don't use the eval version of `setTimeout`. Use `.bind` instead.

```
/in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout(r.bind(null, f), 9) : f()
```

Now, to avoid a file caching you should just attach a random query string to the end of the URI. Usually you'll see `?v=123456789` or something to that effect. We can just use a timestamp in this case.

```
r(function () {
    includeCSSfile(getBaseUrl() + '/css/ext_chat.css?v=' + Date.now())); // getBaseUrl() gives correct url
});
```

Reading material:

- [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
- [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: Thanks for help and great answer. Still - it's interesting why including css file from within html document doesn't use cache but when it's done from within external javascript file - it does.